# Leak de conexiones a base de datos con ThreadLocal al inspeccionar una entidad Hibernate dentro de un ParallelStream

Tags: hibernate, java-8, java-stream

El problema es que al inspeccionar los atributos de una entidad (Hibernate) dentro de un ParallelStream se crean sesiones a la base de datos en cada Thread creado por el Stream dichas sesiones no las puedo cerrar ya que no puedo acceder a la sesion creada por cada Thread interno del Stream, esto provoca una fuga de sesiones que eventualmente termina en que el pool de conexiones se quede sin conexiones a la base de datos ya que las sesiones abiertas por los Thread no son cerradas y por lo tanto no se pueden reutilizar.

El ambiente es una aplicación Backend montado en un contenedor web (Jetty), básicamente el ThreadLocal se utiliza para almacenar la sesión de conexión a la base de datos en lo que dura la petición HTTPRequest del cliente, como el contenedor web crea un Thread para responder a cada petición HTTP entonces la sesion de conexion a la base de datos es almacenado en este ThreadLocal de modo que siempre reutilizo esta sesión en cualquier punto siempre y cuando sea el mismo Thread.

```
public class PoolConexiones {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    ...
}
```

Para obtener la sesión (conexión a la bd de Hibernate) solamente llamo

```
Session sesion = PoolConexiones.threadLocal.get();
```

Y entonces puedo utilizar la sesion para abrir la conexión, crear una transacción, hacer consultas etc y luego cerrar la sesión de modo que regrese al pool en modo standby y sea reutilizada por la siguiente petición HTTPRequest

```
Entidad entidad = EntidadDAO.findById(1);

entidad.getHijos()
    .parallelStream() // <- el problema es cuando uso parallelStream en lugar de stream
    .map(hijo -> hijo.getNietos())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

sesion.close();
```

ParallelStream de Java lo que hace es mejorar el rendimiento del procesamiento del Stream al procesarlo paralelamente utilizando hilos, ojo estos hilos son creados adicionalmente al hilo que procesa la peticion HTTPRequeest por lo tanto no son gestionados por mi, si en el stream accedo a un atributo de una entidad relacionada con otra entidad mediante FetchMode = Lazy, esto provoca que Hibernate realize una consulta a la base de datos pero al estar posiblemente en otro Thread este crea una nueva sesion de hibernate en su propio ThreadLocal para consultar en la base de datos la información de dicho atributo, si no tengo acceso a esos ThreadLocal como hago para cerrar la sesión?

El problema es que la sesion original abierta al hacer la consulta con el DAO se cierra normalmente en la ultima linea pero las sesiones creadas interiormente en el el parallelStream permanecen abiertas lo cual provoca un leak de sesiones y a la final el pool se queda sin sesiones y el sistema colapsa.

Utilizando un stream normal sin paralelización todo va bien, pero tengo que mejorar el rendimiento del proceso y para ello quiero procesar el stream de forma paralela, alguna sugerencia de como puedo gestionar las sesiones del pool al utilizar un ParallelStream?